# 多重構造になっていて重たいクエリの処理

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mysql, backbone.js

現在web上でマンガを作るサービスを作っていて、データ構造が階層的になっています。

novel 
-chapter　　(コマの集合
--entry　　（一つのコマのモデル
---entryBaloon　 　（吹き出しのモデル
---entryCharacter　（画像のモデル

という風な階層構造をbackbone.jsで作っていて、データベースもそれに準じた形で作っているのですが、entryが増えると、サーバからnovel全体をとってこようとした時のパフォーマンスが非常に悪いです。

閲覧だけならキャッシュをとっておけばいいのですが、backboneを使って編集内容を反映しているので、その度にキャッシュをアップデートする訳にもいきません。
現状はトップで表示するものだけキャッシュを作っています。
どうするのが適切でしょうか？

(ソースコードは https://github.com/taizan/ecomaki )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

とりあえず、外部キーになっているカラムにインデックスを張りましょう。マイグレーションでやるなら例えば

```
add_index :chapters, :novel_id
```

です。

それ以上については、

- プロファイルの結果
- 想定されるデータ量
- 要求されるパフォーマンスと現実との差異
- すでにやったチューニング

のなにもかもがわからないので何が適切かも答えようがないです。